# Could I hide certain parts of code in python?

Tags: python

Quite new to coding and I was wondering if I were able to hide of certain parts of the code?
Like what you can do with > def in python... But without using def? What i'm trying to say is that if i had code like this:

```
 x = Hello
 print(x)
```

Could I possibly "hide" it with using some sort of character like this

```
> start
x = Hello
print(x)
> end
```

which would look something like this:

```
> start
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: That would depend on your editor. Many editors support some sort of collapse mark - it's not a feature of the language you're using.

Comment: Currently i'm using visual studio code, was recommended to use that by a friend and i've grown to like it quite a bit.

Comment: According to https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics#_folding - you can use `#region` and `#endregion` around the area you want to make foldable

Answer (score 0):

Glad you're started coding in python! This ability to hide blocks of code (called [Code Folding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_folding)) is found in different [IDEs](https://wiki.python.org/moin/IntegratedDevelopmentEnvironments). Some file editing programs may offer similar functionality, too.

To really answer your question though, this ability is *not* native to python.